# Debian 10 and Parallels Tools issue after restart

Tags: debian, parallels

Given:
Parallels 13 (older version)
MacOS High Sierra (older version)
Debian 10

I just installed Debian 10 in Parallels. I installed Parallels and it said I needed to restart to complete.

I restarted the machine and it hangs before getting to desktop...

[image]

So maybe Debian 10 too new for my old hardware and software :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I learned from Parallels support that Debian 10 is not supported.

https://kb.parallels.com/124223